# JSON key with blank spaces to a Java POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have following `JSON` and the problem is with `Win the match` tag because of the blank spaces:

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 10,
        "odds": {
            "Win the match": {
                "1": {
                    "label": "1",
                    "pos": "1",
                    "odd": "1.51"
                },
                "2": {
                    "label": "2",
                    "pos": "3",
                    "odd": "4.90"
                },
                "N": {
                    "label": "N",
                    "pos": "2",
                    "odd": "3.05"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in one of my `Java Class POJO`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class OddsClass {

    private The1_N22_EMT winTheMatch;

    @JsonProperty("Win the match")
    public The1_N22_EMT getWinTheMatch() { return winTheMatch; }
    @JsonProperty("Win the match")
    public void setWinTheMatch(The1_N22_EMT value) { this.winTheMatch = value; }

}
```

The problem is that this property is not map properly. Please, I need your help to make the correct mapping.

Comment: The error is that OddClass.getWinTheMatch() is null after mapping with Jackson

Comment: Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
      WebTarget webTarget = client.target(System.getProperty("URL_NODEJS")).path("api/liga/obtener");
      Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("access-token", token);
      Response responseCliente = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(null, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

[JSON payload](https://app.quicktype.io/?share=IdOC1hudx3KvCEbGxHjM) is simpler than you think. For dynamic keys use `Map`. In your case you have `Map` in `Map` because you have two levels of dynamic keys. Sometimes generated `POJO` from `JSON` is very complicated. You should generate `POJO` model from `JSON Schema`. Your model could look like below:

```
class ApiWrapper {

    private Api api;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Api {

    private int results;
    private Map<String, Map<String, Match>> odds;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Match {

    private String label;
    private String pos;
    private String odd;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

### Before edit

You have two tricky cases:

- Key with spaces - need to use `JsonProperty` annotation.
- Object with dynamic keys - it should be mapped to `Map<String, ?>`.

Simple example with `POJO` model:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ApiWrapper api = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, ApiWrapper.class);

        System.out.println(api);
    }
}

class ApiWrapper {

    private Api api;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Api {

    private int results;
    private Odds odds;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Odds {

    @JsonProperty("Win the match")
    private Map<String, Match> winTheMatch;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Match {

    private String label;
    private String pos;
    private String odd;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

See also:

- [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo)
- [Nested JSONObject Deserialize to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265312/nested-jsonobject-deserialize-to-jsonobject)

Comment: For deserialize the JSON I'm using the following code:    

import javax.ws.rs.*;

public class OddsFacade {

 public Odds obtenerOdds_x_fixtureID(String fixture_id, String token){
  
  ...//Response responseCliente = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(null, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
       Response responseCliente = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.json(body));
       logger.info(responseCliente.getStatus());
  
           odds = responseCliente.readEntity(Odds.class);
           logger.info(odds.toString());
          return odds;
  
 }
}

Comment: and It gives me the method getWinTheMatch() = null, I just tried with @JsonProperty and Map and the error is the same

Comment: @JeremyGuerraBieberach, Could you create a simple test and properly deserialise `JSON` to `Java` objects like in my example? I'm not sure what the tool do you use but I suggest to start from simple test and prove that model fits to given `JSON` payload. In case it does, you can try with calling web service. I'm not able to help you because I do not know how your model looks like and how you are trying to call web service. I showed you model which works perfectly fine. Please compare it with yours, maybe there are some differences.

Comment: In the following link there are all the POJO Mapping for my example: https://app.quicktype.io/?share=IdOC1hudx3KvCEbGxHjM 
but my problem is the method getWinTheMatch() returns me null

Comment: @JeremyGuerraBieberach, it changes everything. Try to use my model instead of generated by `quicktype`. Generate only `getters` and `setters`.

Comment: @JeremyGuerraBieberach, I'm glad to hear that. Please, read also: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as you are a new user.