# When I try to deserialize my JSON with spaces in the keys into a Java object, it returns null

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am encountering an issue while deserializing a JSON object into a Java object within an AWS Lambda function when the JSON keys contain spaces. The JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
  "Detailed Information": {
    "Organization": "string",
    "Client Full Name": "string",
    "Corporate Name": "string",
    "Description": "string",
    "Contact Phone": "string",
    "Email": "string",
    "Name": "string",
    "UF": "string",
    "Order": "string"
  }
}
```

I have the corresponding Java classes with proper annotations, including @JsonProperty to handle the spaces in the keys. However, when I attempt to deserialize this JSON into a Java object within an AWS Lambda function, the Detailed Description field is consistently null.

Here are my Java classes:

```
// Values class
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Values {
    @JsonProperty("Detailed Information")
    private DetailedInformation detailedInformation;
}

// DetailedInformation class
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DetailedInformation {
    @JsonProperty("Organization")
    private String organization;
    // ... (other fields)
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
package br.com.invoke;

import br.com.invoke.model.DetailedInformation;
import br.com.invoke.model.Values;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

@Log4j2
public class InvokeMyRestAPI implements RequestHandler<Values, String> {
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Values event, Context context) {
        log.info(event);
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event);

            HttpRequest postRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(new URI("https://www.help-me.please.com"))
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonString))
                    .build();

            log.info(jsonString);

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

            HttpResponse<String> postResponse = httpClient.send(postRequest,
                    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            String responseBody = postResponse.body();
            log.info("Response from API: {}", responseBody);

            return responseBody;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Erro ao enviar a solicitação HTTP", e);
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using @JsonProperty annotations, but the issue persists. Any insights into why the DetailedDescription field is not being properly populated during deserialization in the context of an AWS Lambda function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289606/json-key-with-blank-spaces-to-a-java-pojo

Comment: In this case, using @JsonProperty is already working; the issue lies elsewhere in my situation.

Comment: Your Lambda function appears to be serializing, not deserializing. Is your issue that `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event)` doesn't produce the desired result? If so, is `event` actually the thing you think it is or is the serialized data actually somewhere within the event, e.g. `event.body`?

Comment: I try to convert the incoming JSON (input) into an object within my lambda, and this results in a null object. In this case, the event is the JSON that should be transformed into the object.

Comment: Need some clarification here. You said that the DetailedDescription field is not being properly populated during deserialization. By `DetailedDescription`, do you mean the `Description` field within `Detailed Information` or do you mean `Detailed Information` itself?